# MySQL - How to use LEFT JOIN twice?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables, board and vote.

```
create table board (
id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
type varchar(10) not null,
article_id int unsigned,
title varchar(255) not null,
content text not null);

create table vote (
no int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
id int unsigned not null
voter_email varchar(255));
```

In the board table, two types of data are stored, article and reply, and only reply type has a article_id.
So I can count the number of the reply for each articles using the query below.

```
select b.id, b.title, b.content, b2.reply 
from board b left join 
(select article_id, count(id) as reply from board 
where article_id is not null group by article_id) 
b2 on b2.article_id = b.id;

+----+-------+---------+-------+
| id | title | content | reply |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
| 10 | uu    | uuu     |  NULL |
| 12 | eee   | eeee    |     4 |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
```

And I can count the number of the vote for each articles using the query below.

```
select id, count(*) as vote from vote group by id; 
+----+------+
| id | vote |
+----+------+
| 12 |    1 |
+----+------+
```

And I'm now trying to merge the two results into one.

How can I do this?
The result I expect is this:

```
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+
| id | title | content | reply | vote |
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+
| 10 | uu    | uuu     |  NULL | NULL |
| 12 | eee   | eeee    |     4 |    1 |
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use subqueries instead of joins like so:

```
select b.id, 
        b.title, 
        b.content, 
        (select count(*) from board as b2 where article_id = b2.id) as reply, 
        (select count(*) from vote where id = b.id) as votes
from board b ;
```

To keep you system performant you should add indices, one on votes.id and one on board.article_id

Note: I have not been able to test this query since I am not near my computer right now, so you might have to tweak it ;)

I hope this helps :)

Comment: @KimNR - Do **NOT** use correlated subqueries as these tend be utterly slow. Use JOIN based solution.

Comment: @GurV I have seen fast and slow scenarios with joins and subqueries, I usually test different solutions to find what works best. Joins may work better in this scenario, but it probably also depends on the MySQL version and the engines used.

Comment: @mkrmr Seen what? Do you mean my comment about your solution not being optimal? In the world of SQL what may seem simple may not be as efficient as you'd want. If you mean that the correlated queries can be as fast too - then answer is not that often.

Comment: @GurV I accidentally hit post mid-comment ;)

Comment: The answer given by @GurV should also work and may indeed give better performance. You can use EXPLAIN to see how MySQL handles both queries (and of course check the performance by timing the queries).

Answer (score 0):

Just do another `left join`:

```
select b.id, b.title, b.content, b2.reply 
from board b 
left join (
    select article_id, count(id) as reply 
    from board 
    where article_id is not null 
    group by article_id) b2 on b2.article_id = b.id
left join (
    select id, count(*) as vote 
    from vote 
    group by id) AS v on v.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another `left join` at the end:

```
select b.id, b.title, b.content, b2.reply, v.vote
from board b
left join (
    select article_id, count(id) as reply
    from board
    where article_id is not null
    group by article_id
    ) b2 on b2.article_id = b.id
left join (
    select id, count(*) as vote
    from vote
    group by id
    ) v on b.id = v.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

looking to you sample and your schema  you should use a left join and group by

```
select b.id, b.title, b.content, b.reply, sum(v.vote)
from board b 
left join vote on b.id = v.id 
group by b.id, b.title, b.content, b.reply
```